# How to identify domain in ddd?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I want to build an application and I want to apply ddd rules to my architectural design.

I describe my application:

In the database I have tables: `report`, `notification`, `user`, `event`, `company`, `stakeholder`, `transaction`.

The application will need authentication so I do it against `user` table.

In the application I need to display and make a crud operation on the tables in the database I was mention above.

And each of them have it's own page in my application. for example:

```
 /reports (create, delete, get one, get all, search, edit)
 /reports/:id 
 /notifications (create, delete, get one, get all, search, edit)
 /notifications/:id 
 /events (create, delete, get one, get all, search, edit)
 ...
```

In the report table I have: `id`, `title`, `lastUpdate`, `body`, `company`, `event`.
Each report have a list of companies and list of events. the user can edit the report and change the `title` and the `body` and he can also add/remove `company` from the list so goes to `event`.

```
const reports = [
{ id, title, body, companies: [{ id, name, ... }], events: [{ id, ...}]}
]
```

I also want to have separate pages for: `company`, `event`, `stakeholder` to display list of them (company has own page, event has own page..) in order to `add/edit/delete` each entity.

The transaction items should belong to `stakeholder`. I mean each stakeholder have many `transactions`. and same goes here: i want to `add/edit/delete` each transaction.

```
 stakeholders = [{ id, name, transactions: [{ id, ... }]}, ...]
```

** each operation `add/edit/delete/view` lives in it own page.

--

So I decide to named the domains in my application:
auth, report, notification, events, companies, stakeholder, stakeholder-transactions.

And this is lead me to create domains with features following this folder structure:

```
 reports
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-view (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
  feature-search (use the domain)
 auth
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-login (use the domain)
  feature-register (use the domain)
  feature-forgot-password (use the domain)
 notification:
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-create-new (use the domain)
  feature-remove (use the domain)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
 company:
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-create (use the domain)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
  feature-view (use the domain)
  feature-search (use the domain)
 event:
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-create (use the domain)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
  feature-view (use the domain)
  feature-search (use the domain)
 stakeholder:
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-create (use the domain)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
  feature-view (use the domain)
  feature-search (use the domain)
 stakeholder-transaction:
  domain (the bl is here)
  feature-create (use the domain)
  feature-edit (use the domain)
  feature-list (use the domain)
  feature-view (use the domain)
  feature-search (use the domain)
```

I'm thinking about the area of responsibility of each parts of my application. but does it match the ddd domain requirements? the separation of those folder are matching the ddd domain requirements? because something is not end up, the domain should be isolated. but sometimes I'll need `notification` to create from the `report` and `report` is have a `company` and `event` inside.

I really appreciated the help in trying to resolve this conflict

Answer (score 0):

They are not "domains" but modules, and they seems ok.

You describe your application starting with "In the database I have tables:" and "In the application I need to display and make a crud operation on the tables in the database"

So seems to be database/tables centric, a CRUD application, DDD seems overkill for this.

To check the DDD modules/bounded context you should start looking at your domain for what it is, not for the tables you need.

Comment: Sorry but I so confused right now. can't tell how to think to determine what is the domain. let's say I want to make this application according to ddd even it overkill. just for learning. the client say "I want to display reports in the page and I want to be able to view and edit them". "the report can be lock/unlock so only one person can edit", "also I want to be able to add/remove from favorite", "give me a page that show the favorite reports", "I want to be able to search reports by criteria".
So those question are not enough to determine report as domain?

Comment: What that questions tells me is that, in your domain you could have a `Report` entity that has a bunch of possible operations that could be execute on it. The lock/unlock one maybe is defining some kind lifecycle for it, but would like to understand more, like can it be locked for one week? Or is it lock/unlock on a single operation of edit. The favorite operation, is something related to the user not the `Report`, the `Report` invariants/lifecycle seems to don't care about it being the "favorite" of a user.

Comment: DDD is about the processes, not the entities. It is about the interactions between entities, not their shape.

Comment: I read your answer and comments for at least 10 times, word by word.  the lock on the report is on a single operation on edit. and the favorite is per user, I have collection of reports which are user favorite. so it doesn't belong to Report entity? can I have Domain called Report which is area of responsibility, and the entities are: `reportModel` and `favoriteModel`? "area of responsibility" is not what domain means?

Comment: or do you mean about "DDD is about the processes", Report is the domain but the features are: "add to favorite", "remove from favorite", "show the list", "lock the report" so on..?

Comment: Do you say "DDD is about the processes". this is means for flight app example, the way to think is: booking then luggage then boarding will complete the all flight process? booking luggage and boarding those are good domains? so I should thinking in terms of "what after in the next/process"?

Comment: In this node-ddd repo they creates `article` and `comments` as domains. so they took entities wrap it with repositories and so on. they are doing it wrong? because it's not "process" flow.
https://github.com/talyssonoc/node-api-boilerplate/blob/main/src/article/domain/Article.ts

Comment: The fact is that you don't need DDD for modeling a blog. When I say DDD is overkill for a CRUD thing is because, 90% of the time this CRUD systems don't have complex rules, neither they are big. I would suggest you to read this link https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping/ . Now that is an example and to show how to split two models it can also be good, but on a real implementation you will have a "Blog" bounded context (not domain), and in it the Article, and MAYBE the comment aggregate (it can also be an entity part of the Article aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

in a very simple sentence I can say domain: is problem space and it comes from a domain expert. in fact, it's about why this software is created and what core problems this software will address. also, DDD is rooted in a language not taking care about which kinda databases you have.

Comment: okay not according to tables in the database. I watch a lot of youtube videos and go for every question in stackoverflow website. The examples they refer to are very easy to understand because let's say I have a flight app. then the domains are for example boarding, booking.

Comment: so yeah it very easy to tell. but in my application according to my client needs I try to understand how to apply those rules to my application. for me `report` is a very large domain such as `booking` with a lot of features such `lock`, `unlock`, `get`, `delete`, `publish` so on just like booking have `cancel`, `search`, `manage` features.

Comment: the client say "I want to display reports in the page and I want to be able to view and edit them". "the report can be lock/unlock so only one person can edit", "also I want to be able to add/remove from favorite", "give me a page that show the favorite reports", "I want to be able to search reports by criteria". So those question are not enough to determine report as domain?

Comment: watch these videos too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfEpw2WXXyk&list=PLL7eYRjNwJK3g865rcCiEmVk21hjq9Rzi